# Can I develop non-Microsoft web applications/websites on Microsoft IDEs?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-applications, webmatrix

Is it possible for me to develop web applications that do not use ASP.NET or MVC.NET or basically anything microsoft (e.g. it uses HTML, JS, CSS, Node.js, jQuery, PHP, AJAX) on the Microsoft Visual Express 2012 and/or the Microsoft Webmatrix

Comment: Fine i can't, the answer is no... right?

Comment: No - the answer is have patience :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebMatrix to develop sites using non-Microsoft technologies such as PHP and Node. It has [built-in PHP code completion](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/php.aspx) and offers some PHP templates. It [has the same features](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/node.aspx) in support of Nodejs development. It also includes a Nuget client to make it easy to download jQuery into your site and it's default templates are HTML5.

Visual Studio does not offer any official PHP or Nodejs support. There [is an extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/885a8a68-e38b-4e6a-b96d-083d5572b645) that offers some kind of support for Nodejs.